# Real time pushing

Tags: ajax, real-time, push

Ten updates a second, what would be the best way to do that? Aside from WebSockets (not fully implemented) what can accomplish this?

Would creating a Java Applet be worth it? Can you interact with the DOM in that fashion?

Answer (score 4):

First 10 updates a second does not imply 10 messgaes a second to the browser, you can piggy-back updates to send one message a second (say) - no point in updates faster than the eye can see.

[Commetd/Bayeuax](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a JAVA Applet or any other Applet like Flex or Silverlight would be able to handle that speed.

As for the server side, I think you need a push server, you can't reach that rate of 10 responses / sec if each response is triggered by a client side polling request.
You you've got to let the flow of data come asynchronously from the server.

Examples of push server : Push Framework : http://www.pushframework.com